# Slow NSolve of a system of 8 nonlinear equations inside Manipulate gives $Aborted

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate

I study economics and I have the ambition to numerically solve a nonlinear system of 8 equations. My goal is to see how some equilibrium objects resulting from the solutions of this system change with the value of some parameters. I am trying with `Manipulate[NSolve[...]]`, but the answer of *Mathematica* is "aborted". Any guesses? Is it better to use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)? Did I write the equations in the wrong way? Or is my problem simply too complex? Below my code, thanks

```
Manipulate[NSolve[{Nl == (wl1/(
   A1g*λ*η*(1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)^λ))^(1/(λ*η - 1))*(1 + (wh1/wl1)^(η/(η - 1))*((
      1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)/(ah*ϕh1)))^((
   1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1)) + (wl2/(
   A2g*λ*η*(1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)^λ))^(1/(λ*η - 
    1))*(1 + (wh2/wl2)^(η/(η - 1))*((
      1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)/(ah*ϕh2)))^((
   1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1)), Nm == (wm1/(A1g*η*ϕm1*am))^(1/(η - 1)) + (wm2/(
  A2g*η*ϕm2*am))^(1/(η - 1)), Nh == (wl1/(
   A1g*λ*η*(1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)^λ))^(1/(λ*η - 
    1))*(1 + (wh1/wl1)^(η/(η - 1))*((
      1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)/(ah*ϕh1)))^((
   1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1))*(wh1/wl1)^(
  1/(η - 1))*((1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)/(
   ah*ϕh1))^(1/(η - 1)) + (wl2/(
   A2g*λ*η*(1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)^λ))^(1/(λ*η - 
    1))*(1 + (wh2/wl2)^(η/(η - 1))*((
      1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)/(ah*ϕh2)))^((
   1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1))*(wh2/wl2)^(
  1/(η - 1))*((1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)/(
   ah*ϕh2))^(1/(η - 1)), (wl1/wl2) == (pH1/
 pH2)^α, (wm1/wm2) == (pH1/pH2)^α, (wh1/
 wh2) == (pH1/
 pH2)^α, (wl1/(
   A1g*λ*η*(1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)^λ))^(1/(λ*η - 
    1))*(1 + (wh1/wl1)^(η/(η - 1))*((
      1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)/(ah*ϕh1)))^((
   1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1))*
  wl1 + (wm1/(A1g*η*ϕm1*am))^(1/(η - 1))*
  wm1 + (wl1/(
   A1g*λ*η*(1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)^λ))^(1/(λ*η - 
    1))*(1 + (wh1/wl1)^(η/(η - 1))*((
      1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)/(ah*ϕh1)))^((
   1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1))*(wh1/wl1)^(
  1/(η - 1))*((1 - ϕm1 - ϕh1)/(
   ah*ϕh1))^(1/(η - 1))*wh1 == (
pH1*H)/α, (wl2/(
   A2g*λ*η*(1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)^λ))^(1/(λ*η - 
    1))*(1 + (wh2/wl2)^(η/(η - 1))*((
      1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)/(ah*ϕh2)))^((
   1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1))*
  wl2 + (wm2/(A2g*η*ϕm2*am))^(1/(η - 1))*
  wm2 + (wl2/(
   A2g*λ*η*(1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)^λ))^(1/(λ*η - 
    1))*(1 + (wh2/wl2)^(η/(η - 1))*((
      1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)/(ah*ϕh2)))^((
   1 - λ)/(λ*η - 1))*(wh2/wl2)^(
  1/(η - 1))*((1 - ϕm2 - ϕh2)/(
   ah*ϕh2))^(1/(η - 1))*wh2 == (pH2*H)/α}, {wh1, wh2, wm1, wm2, wl1, wl2, pH1, pH2}, Reals], {α, 0.001, 0.999}, {λ, 1, 1.2}, {η, 0.6, 0.8}, {ϕm1, 0.001, 0.999}, {ϕh1, 1 - ϕm1, 0.999}, {ϕm2, 0.001, 0.999}, {ϕh2, 0.001, 0.999}, {ah, 1, 2}, {am, 1, 2}, {A1g, 1, 2}, {A2g, 1, 2}, {Nh, 1, 2}, {Nm, 1, 2}, {Nl, 1, 2}, {H, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Fortunately the answer to your question was not related at all to the details of your equation. In the future, you shouldn't have expectation of anybody volunteering their time to look for mistakes in such a wall of code. Always use **a minimal working example of working code and data** to show specifically what you are working with in a way that makes it easy for anybody to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get [`$Aborted`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Aborted.html) because [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) is constrained by [`DynamicEvaluationTimeout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicEvaluationTimeout.html) and your calculation is taking longer than the timeout value.

For example

```
Style[
 Manipulate[
  Pause[3];
  1 + 2
  , {z, 0, 1}
  ]
 , DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 1
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You would have found out by yourself if you had [searched for `$Aborted` and `Manipulate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%24Aborted+Manipulate) in this site.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the suggested option but either I still get $Aborted or, if I set an higher value, it crashes. I've also tried to restrict manipulation range to only one values for the parameters but still doesn't work. I am wondering whether I am using the right command to solve my problem, thanks

Comment: @FabioCerina lookup `SynchronousEvaluation`, `ControlActive` and related functions.